# Docker is deprecated. What is the recommended way to deploy?

Tags: docker

[Apparently](https://hub.docker.com/r/eosio/eos/), Docker support has been deprecated:

> This image is now deprecated. Future builds will discontinue on
> January 1st, 2019. This image will be removed on June 1st, 2019.

However, as recently as late October [pull requests](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/6131) supporting Docker were being merged.

What's going on?

1. Can anyone point me to discussions that describe the rationale behind dropping Docker support?
2. Does this mean that using EOS.IO in Docker is no longer recommended?
3. What is the recommended way for deploying EOS.IO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I could find on the discussion of moving from Docker; however, upon examining the release notes, I could find no elaboration of the rationale.

> We're moving away from Docker images in favor of the pre-built
>   binaries. See https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/latest and
>   https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/releases/latest.

The only 2 references to docker in recent release were:

> - Build and push docker containers to automation gcr (#[**6131**](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/6131))
> - removed eosiocpp reference in dockerfile (#[**6250**](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/6250))

[**Issue Link**](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/6339)

---

And this is from [**the docs:**](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/v1.7.0/docs/introduction)

> The Docker image is no longer maintained has been deprecated. The
>   eosio/eos image from Dockerhub will be available until its sunset on
>   June 29 2018

---

More on what is recommended in [**the docs**](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/installing-the-contract-development-toolkit):

> Starting from 1.3.x, CDT supports Mac OS X brew, Linux Debian and RPM
>   packages. The easiest option to install would be using one of these
>   package systems. Pick one installation method only.

Answer (score 0):

Best way using binaries. Its smooth and you get components installed quickly.
For Mac, refer the following post, covers installation to usage.

https://medium.com/@vjverma/eos-concepts-for-first-timers-b02c9284af85